# Can any one explain why this section of code is giving run time error?

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am not finding the correct output of this program.It giving run time error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c = 5, no = 10;
    do {
        no /= c;
    } while(c--);

    printf ("%d\n", no);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `c` will eventually become `0` and you will divide by zero.  Notice that when `c` is `1`, `while(c--)` will be true, but `c` will become `0` inside the loop because of the postdecrement.

Answer (score 5):

It's division by zero. Since you are using a post-decrement in your loop counter `c`, it is becoming `0` in the last iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Now that you know the reason for the run time error from the answer by @EugeneSh, here's how you can fix it.

```
do {
    no /= c;
} while(--c);  // Use pre-increment instead of post-increment.
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition the all these answer above I just want to say it's better to check whether a number is zero before division -

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c = 5, no = 10;
    do {
        if(c!=0){
           no /= c;
        }
    } while(c--);

    printf ("%d\n", no);
    return 0;
}
```

This will prevent these kind of runtime error.

Hope it will helps.
Thanks a lot.